# Expressing and creating a function

Tags: functions

> The intensity of illumination at any point from a light source is proportional to the square of the reciprocal of the distance between the point and the light source. Two lights, one having an intensity eight times that of the other, are 6m apart. Consider a point $x$ m away from the stronger light and is between the two lights. Express the total intensity of illumination at this point in terms of $x$.

I’m very loss with how to make use of the numbers to form a function in terms of $x$, I need a guide on how to start this..

I know that the total intensity $= (1)/(x^2)$ but after this I’m not sure how to use the “8 times intensity” and the “6m” value into the function.

Comment: You are expected to add the illumination that arrives at the object from the two lights.  How far is the object from the weaker light?

Comment: @RossMillikan  It is $(6-x)$ but, I can create two reciprocal functions with $x$ and $6-x$ but what do I need to do with the stronger light being $8$ times stronger?

Comment: The total intensity is $L_1/x^2+L_2/y^2$ where $y$ is the distance from the weaker light, and $L_1$ is eight times $L_2$. What is $y$ in terms of $x$? Hint: this is where you use the 6m. We can also remove the $L_2$ term, so the final answer just has $L_1$ and $x$ in it.